# Using jquery dot dot dot to create a more/less text reveal

Tags: jquery

We're trying to use jQuery dot to toggle/reveal the text that gets truncated.

Everything is working great on reveal except we can't work out how to:

1. Remove the initial truncated content on reveal (the original truncated text remains)
2. Display a single more link on reveal (we end up with two but only the original one closes the reveal)

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated - our jquery is pretty basic sorry.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsuojcb1/2/

Our jQuery setup:

```
// Initialise when dom is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Initialise if .more-reveal is on the page
  if ($(".more-reveal")[0]) {

    // truncate text on page load
    $(".more-reveal").dotdotdot({
      watch: "window",
      after: "a.more-link"
    });

    // store original content before truncation
    var content = $(".more-reveal").triggerHandler("originalContent");

    // reveal text on more button click
    $('.more-reveal').find('a.more-link').on('click', function () {
      if (content != '') {
        $(this).closest('.more-reveal').toggleClass('more-closed more-open').append(content);
      } else {
        $(this).closest('.more-reveal').toggleClass('more-closed more-open');
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the second button isn't firing on click is because the event is no longer attached to the copied element. Use clone to copy the element and events.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lsuojcb1/7/

```
// store original content before trancation
var content = $(".more-reveal").triggerHandler("originalContent");
//remove the link button
content.splice(-2,2);

// reveal text on more button click
$('.more-reveal').find('a.more-link').on('click', function () {
  if (content != '') {
    $(this).closest('.more-reveal').toggleClass('more-closed more-open').append(content);
      //if open, CLONE link button and add, hide short text and button 
      //else remove the cloned button and show short text
      if ($(this).closest('.more-reveal').hasClass('more-open')) {
          $(this).closest('.more-reveal').children('p').first().hide();
          $(this).closest('.more-reveal').children('a').first().hide();
          $(this).closest('.more-reveal').append($(this).clone(true));
      } else {
          $(this).closest('.more-reveal').children('p').first().show();
          $(this).closest('.more-reveal').children('a').first().show();
          $(this).closest('.more-reveal').children('a').last().remove();
      }
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.more-reveal').toggleClass('more-closed more-open');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: no need to toggle the class if element is being replaced

Comment: Thanks heaps, sorry for my basic jquery but this is starting get confusing - how would I now show a less link to revert back to the truncated version with a more link? When I try your code there's no more link to close the reveal.

Comment: Yes it's a little hacky as I guess it requires the initial content to be limited to one paragraph - is that right?

Comment: Yeah, It will only hide the initial content first paragraph and more link.